# Get multiple jQuery-click-functions into one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a few modules on my website and each module can be disabled by the user.
**My problem is that I have for each module a whole script, therefore my question: How can I get this into one script (-> maybe one jQuery-click-function?)**

(I leave out the database-part whether the module is enabled or disabled because it's not relevant)

**HTML**

```
<div class="border f12" style="width: 200px">
    <b>Weather Module</b>
    <p style="text-align: justify; margin: 0px;">Description</p><br>';
    <button action="del" startmodule="weather" id="submit_weather"><span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-trash"></span><span class="ui-button-text">disable/enable</span></button>
</div>
<div class="border f12" style="width: 200px">
    <b>Infos Module</b>
    <p style="text-align: justify; margin: 0px;">Description</p><br>';
    <button action="del" startmodule="infos" id="submit_infos"><span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-trash"></span><span class="ui-button-text">disable/enable</span></button>
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
<script>
    $("#submit_infos").click(function() {
        $(".ajax_response").empty();
        $.post("settings/settings_startmodule.php", 
            {
                ajax_action: $("#submit_infos").attr("action"),
                ajax_startmodule: $("#submit_infos").attr("startmodule")
            },
            function(data) {
                $(".ajax_response").html(data);
            }
        );
    });
    $("#submit_weather").click(function() {
        $(".ajax_response").empty();
        $.post("settings/settings_startmodule.php", 
            {
                ajax_action: $("#submit_weather").attr("action"),
                ajax_startmodule: $("#submit_weather").attr("startmodule")
            },
            function(data) {
                $(".ajax_response").html(data);
            }
        );
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your methods are identical, and can easily be converted to use a single `click` handler for all modules. You need some way to select all the buttons used in a module - from your HTML I can spot a bunch ways

- `div.f12 button` as a selector - fairly good
- `button[startmodule]` as a selector - fairly good but slower
- `button[id^='submit_']` as a selector - fairly bad! slow and possibly error prone

However, the best way would be to just have a common class on each button and use that as the selector.

```
<button class="module-button" action="del" startmodule="infos">...</button>
```

Given a common way of selecting all buttons simply use this script (assumes you have a common class `module-button` on all buttons):

```
$(".module-button").click(function() {
    $(".ajax_response").empty();
    var $this = $(this); // variable refers to the button having been clicked
    $.post("settings/settings_startmodule.php", 
        {
            ajax_action: $this.attr("action"),
            ajax_startmodule: $this.attr("startmodule")
        },
        function(data) {
            $(".ajax_response").html(data);
        }
    );
});
```